# Database Design - Column has values of different types stored as varchar

Tags: java, c#, mysql, sql-server, design-patterns

We have a table that has two columns:

```
tblCategory

Id | Name
1    Brand
2    Band
3    Price
```

Now we have another table that defines the ranges or brackets for the Categories

```
tblCategoryBrackets

Id | Value | Category_Id
1     5         3
2     10        3
3     20        3
4     Wilson    1
5     Babolat   1
6     Head      1
```

Now Given a price and a brand we need to get the brackets for them.
eg : Given `Price = 17` and `Brand = Dunlop` the query should return the bracket with `Id = 2 and 5`
Because `Price = 17` lies between price brackets `10 and 20` and `Brand = Dunlop` lies between `Babolat and Head`. So we return the lower category bracket id.

The problem with our implementation is since the `Value` in `tblCategoryBrackets` is of type `Varchar` all comparisons are string based so `5` is being treated greater than `10`.

How should the tables be designed?

**Option A** -Should i have different tables for different categories.

My opinion - Would lead to a table explosion. But would be flexible and the values can be typed. For `Price Decimal`, For `Brand Varchar` etc. Maintenance might be an issue as whenever a new category comes in the database would need updating. Would result in downtime. In the code retrieve data from the appropriate table based on the category type.

**Option B** -Do it the way we have it now.

But in the code(Java/C#) form the query such that for particular categories a particular `CAST` is done based on the category value type and then the comparison is done.
Cant figure out the class design for that.

Would appreciate a reply from the experts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would normalize the database properly. This is one of the most common ways to abuse database design.

If we were to convert this to 3rd normal form, Brand would have its own table, Band(?) would probably have its own table and the price would be in the table where other item data is included (or if that table doesn't exist, then create it).

I don't see how this would cause "table explosion", unless you've simplified your example enormously.

```
ItemTable
Id | Itemname | ItemBrand | ItemBand
1  | Foobar   | 2         | 3     

CategoryTable
Id | CategoryName
1  | Foo
2  | Bar
3  | Baz
```

etc.

Comment: Appreciate the reply. Yes the example is simplified a lot. But would   you consider maintenance a issue here. If a new category comes in a new table would need to be created. Whereas in the other case it could be handled in the code itself. Your thoughts? Thanks again. BTW What is the ItemTable?

Comment: Yes, that's often (always?) the rationalization behind this. "If things change, we'll have to modify the schema". The truth is that this database anti-pattern will cause its own maintenance (and other) problems, so it's not like this solves anything. Ask yourself (or other people) how often would you actually need to change the schema to add a new table, and whether adding a new table is actually such a big issue. Besides, adding a new category (essentially a column) doesn't require a new table, a simple alter table will suffice. Go 3rd normal form if you can, you won't regret it.

Comment: Oh! Thanks, adding a row in the CategoryTable would add a category, but then would need to add its brackets, for that would need to create different CategoryBracket tables for that, because price would have `DECIMAL` type bracket values and brand would have `VARCHAR`. Am i in the right direction?

Comment: Take a look at this real world story about somebody who worked on a team that decided they would use this type of "design", known as EAV or Entity Attribute Value. This type of thing has its place but not for everything. https://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/

Comment: @Sean: a Wonderful read, Thanks! I understand the problem, but still can't figure out the solution, should i create diff tables for string values, int values? And the category would have a CategoryDataType column that would say whether the category brackets should be int or string etc.? And according to that redirect queries? If you could find some time to post an answer, would greatly help a learner like me. Thanks

Comment: It would help if you edited the post to include some actual use cases. Why do you search with `Price=17` and `Brand=Dunlop` and what do you do with the results. What are these category brackets used for?